# auto-scripting using crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron

this is my first time at scripting. I tried some autoscripting by just echo -ing my name every one minute. the crontab file was installed successfully but the echo comman doesn't seem to execute. Please help out .! (bash scripting in LINUX ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: What is the command you are trying? Where are you expecting to see the output?

Comment: `echo`ing where?, to a file? remember `crond` doesn't have a terminal associated...

Comment: I want to view the output in terminal .. I didn't know that crontab didn't have a terminal associated with it. how do i see the crontab output file

Comment: what is the content of crontab -l ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the output in a terminal, just write [`tty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tty) in any terminal and you'll see something like this:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/1
```

Then, redirect the output of your script/command in your **crontab** to `/dev/pts/1`.
Example:

```
* * * * * your_user echo hello world > /dev/pts/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
* * * * * /bin/echo $USER >> /tmp/crontab_output
```

Then check

```
/tmp/crontab_output
```

file